# H1B valid period and travel to USA

Tags: usa

My H1B visa is expiring on Sep 30th 2017 and I am planning to travel to India now. So When I travel back to USA my visa duration will be less than 6 months. Is that will create a problem during immigration checking in USA?

Answer (score 3):

No, you should not have any problems when crossing US border.

Visa validity is determined by [22CFR 41.112](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/22CFR/HTML/22CFR/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-500/0-0-0-1810.html). First paragraph states that The alien may use the visa in making application for admission for the entire period of validity of a nonimmigrant visa.